# nginx lua reading content encoding header

Tags: nginx, lua, http-headers

I'm trying to read the Content-Encoding in a header_filter_by_lua block. I test using chrome's developer tools while requesting an url which respond with Content-Encoding: gzip. I use these checks:

```
local test1 = ngx.var.http_content_encoding
local test2 = ngx.header.content_encoding
local test3 = ngx.resp.get_headers()["Content-Encoding"]
```

and all of them give empty/nil value. Getting User-Agent in same way is successful so what's the problem with Content-Encoding?

Answer (score 7):

`ngx.var.http_content_encoding` - would return request's (not response's) header

API below work for read access in context of `header_filter_by_lua_block` and later phases:

`ngx.header.content_encoding` works for me always and is the right way.

If it doesn't work - check https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_transform_underscores_in_response_headers

`ngx.resp.get_headers()["Content-Encoding"]` also work, but not efficient to obtain single header.

Comment: I tried to get the response headers, but I am getting only "connection:keep-alive" header. Not getting any other headers. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from request use following

```
ngx.req.get_headers()["content_encoding"]
```